# Disable location services when leaving map screen (Flutter )

Tags: flutter, gps, google-geolocation

I’m using this flutter package to manage location services in my flutter app : https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

I want to disable the active state of the location service (after some seconds) when the user is not on the map screen .

Please help .

Answer (score 0):

You can dispose of it after the user leaves the particular screen:

```js
void dispose() {
    // Dispose any controller...
    super.dispose();
}
```